# You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... 'UNIQUE `UK6i9q4suadww4j167aqe2h6aqj`' at line 4

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, flyway

I am trying to remove Unique constraint from a column using flyway DB migration in spring-boot. But I am not able to figure out the right query for that. Here is my existing query

```
ALTER TABLE `choices` DROP UNIQUE `UK6i9q4suadww4j167aqe2h6aqj`;
```

Here is the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNIQUE `UK6i9q4suadww4j167aqe2h6aqj`' at line 4
```

*Note: the above query is working fine if I am running it through PHPMyAdmin. Its ask for confirmation and then remove it.*

Comment: Do you have some comments in that line ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Not in that line but above the line.

Comment: Try to remove it , just in case , if the error is still there , just revert it again.

Comment: Hey thanks for suggesting the removing of the comment. There was no problem with the comment but I did find the error and it was in a different query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ALTER TABLE `choices` DROP index `UK6i9q4suadww4j167aqe2h6aqj`;
```

This will only work , if there in no foreign key defined that references your key.
.
In which case you have to drop the foreign keys first.

Comment: I have also tried it but it didn't work either. This was the exact query.`ALTER TABLE `choices` DROP INDEX `UK6i9q4suadww4j167aqe2h6aqj`;`

Comment: Please tell me the exact error message. Mysql 8 doesn't give an error message in my server

Comment: Hey, I completely agree with you. The query is working when I try to run in PHPMyAdmin as I mentioned. The problem I am getting when I am trying to run this through flyway DB migration for spring-boot. My bad, I should have mentioned it in the title.

Comment: you must have a new error message. please post it anyway.